# Spring Cloud Stream kafka- MessageConversionException

Tags: kafka-consumer-api, spring-cloud-stream

While consuming messages from Avro topics, getting the below exception

org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: No converter found from actual payload type 'org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData$Record' to expected payload type 'com.gap.avro.TestClass', failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload]

Below is the consumer method

```
@StreamListener(channel)
  public void handleActivity(Message<TestClass> message,
      @Header(name = "deliveryAttempt", defaultValue = "1") int deliveryAttempt) {
{
```

Answer (score 0):

You're simply missing `AvroSchemaMessageConverter` which depending on the version of the framework you are using comes from either spring-cloud-schema-registry module or spring-cloud-function.
Also annotation-based programming model is long deprecated and is no longer part of he code base, so @StreamListener will not work with the upcoming 4.x release. The lates release now is 3.2

Comment: The version am using is 4.8 and I could see the AvroSchemaMessageConverter
build.gradle-implementation "com.azure:azure-cosmos:4.8.0"